# Word for "loud words?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word for that? Example sentence:

> "There's nothing wrong with my mood!" Mary cupped her mouth as soon as the _____ left her mouth. "Sorry, I didn't mean to shout."

Comment: Take your pick from [**694** Synonyms for **outburst**.](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/outburst)

Comment: The word "ejaculation" used to be used in this context, but it's meaning is now too tied to the sexual sense to be used in any other context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Exclamation** works, I think.

From OED:

> A sudden cry or remark expressing surprise, strong emotion, or pain.

Answer (score 1):

Cry, as a noun, works excellently.

From [dictionary.com:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cry?s=t)

> Cry - the act or sound of crying; any loud utterance or exclamation; a
>   shout, scream, or wail.

My example:

"She cried out, then hastily cupped a hand over her mouth. It would do more harm than good if they heard her pained cries."

Answer (score 1):

I feel that *exclamation* is a good suggestion but, if you want something that sounds a little different, you might try **vociferation**:

> #### Vociferation
>
> *noun*
>
> - To utter (something) or cry out loudly and vehemently, especially in protest (disapproval)

[[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vociferation)]